# Jquery display field names based on selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

**JS**

I have a form which contains a dropdown with various fields. I want to display the fields which has been selected from a dropdown and the rest of the fields should be hidden.

```
$( document ).on('ready page:load', function() {
var selectedValues = [];

    $('#customer_detail_field_list').on( 'change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var checked = $(this).val();
        console.log(checked)
        var currentSelectedArray = []
        if (checked) {
          var selectedOption = [];
          var selectedIncrement = 0;
          jQuery.grep(checked, function(el) {

              if (jQuery.inArray(el, selectedValues) == -1) selectedOption.push(el);


              selectedIncrement++;

          });
          console.log(selectedOption)
          var unselectedOption = [];
          var unselectedIncrement = 0;
          jQuery.grep(selectedValues, function(el) {

              if (jQuery.inArray(el, checked) == -1) unselectedOption.push(el);


              unselectedIncrement++;

          });
          console.log(unselectedOption)
          // console.log($(this).val());
          // console.log(table.column);
          // console.log(checked)
          var column = table.column( checked - 1 );
          // console.log(column)


          // Toggle the visibility
          column.visible( ! column.visible() );
          selectedValues = checked.slice();

        }
         if (selectedOption == true)

    });
```

**view**

```
.col-sm-12
  .main-login.main-center-customer
    = form_for(@customer_detail) do |f|
      .field-list
        = f.label :field_list,"Choose the fields to be displayed", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.select :field_list, options_for_select(CustomerDetail::INSERT_FIELD_LIST_CUSTOMER),{}, {prompt: "Field List", class: "select-fields", "data-live-search": "true", multiple: 'multiple'}

    %table.display{:id => "example", :cellspacing => "0", :width => "100%"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th.sorting{"aria-controls" => "example", "aria-label" => "Name: activate to sort column ascending", :colspan => "1", :rowspan => "1", :style => "width: 50px;", :tabindex => "0"} Customer Name
          %th.sorting_desc{"aria-controls" => "example", "aria-label" => "Position: activate to sort column ascending", "aria-sort" => "descending", :colspan => "1", :rowspan => "1", :style => "width: 50px;", :tabindex => "0"} Customer ID
          %th{:style => "width: 20px;"} Address
          %th{:style => "width: 20px;"} State
          %th{:style => "width: 20px;"} Email
          %th{:style => "width: 20px;"} Website
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Service Tax Reg No
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Local Sales Tax No
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Residential Type
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Attention To
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} City
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Pin code
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Contact No
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Business Type
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} PAN No
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Central sales Tax No
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Business Center
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Opening Bal
          %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Currency Type
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Name
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Contact No
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Address
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} State
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Pin Code
          / %th{:style => "width: 50px;"} Delivery Address


      %tbody
        - @customer_details.each do |customer|
          %tr
            %td= customer.customer_name
            %td= customer.customer_id
            %td= customer.address
            %td= customer.state
            %td= customer.email
            %td= customer.website
            %td= customer.service_tax_reg_no
            %td= customer.local_sales_tax_reg_no
            %td= customer.residential_type
            %td= customer.attention_to
            %td= customer.city
            %td= customer.pin_code
            %td= customer.contact_no
            %td= customer.business_type
            %td= customer.pan_no
            %td= customer.central_sales_tax_no
            %td= customer.business_center
            %td= customer.opening_bal
            %td= customer.currency_type
```

the problem is I dont know how to give condition for the fields to be displayed.I want to display only selectedOption from that array.can someone help me. Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: Please show a self contained example using the snippet editor correctly, e.g. adding relevant html

Comment: I've added a relevent view file only. here I've added the view file which contains a dropdown list in it. Using Jquery I have to display only selected fields.

Comment: But that does not give us any HTML to look at. Show the rendered HTML in the snippet so the code can be manipulated. I do not want to see the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this for a single value selected in the dropdown (#my_dropdown_id). You might have to adapt if you have a multiple selections.

```
# jquery function to show conditional fields - attach this to onchange event of drop down
function showConditionalFields() {
    $(".conditional").hide()
    selected_condition = $('#my_dropdown_id :selected').text()
    $(".conditional.".concat(selected_condition)).show()
};
```

then add `.conditional.valuex` around the fields you want to display/hide

```
.conditional.value1
    # tags when value1 is selected
.conditional.value2
    # tags when value2 is selected
```